# Create Bar Chart

Tags: python, dataframe, python-visual

How to create a bar chart like below chart for below question using Python?

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9ih0.jpg)

Question: plot job role based on number of individuals who have have master degree AND earn <=50K in the United States

My table is below which I have imported from CSV file.

Degree     job rol  Country    earning
Bachelor    Admin     US.     <=50k
Master      HR.     England    >=50k

I tried many ways. But could not do it

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Without any code or a sample of your data, it's not possible to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and import `numpy as np` to make a bar graph. Create an array called `y = np.array([...])` for example, and create a function called `plt.bar()`. From there, you can fill in the height and your y variable to create a graph as you desire.
Finally, just type `plt.show()` to display the graph.